# Flattening PDF using iText v8.0 for merging multiple forms works but PDF contains errors

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext7

I have a fairly simple program that takes PDF files and merges them together using iText7 v8.0.  I pass a array of files along with the output file to this function:

```
Dim pdfDoc As New PdfDocument(New PdfWriter(outputPath))
Dim merger As New PdfMerger(pdfDoc)
For Each file In pdfFiles
    Dim newDoc As New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(file))
    merger.Merge(newDoc, 1, newDoc.GetNumberOfPages())
    newDoc.Close()
Next
pdfDoc.Close()
merger.Close()
```

This has worked fine but recently someone tried to merge a bunch of PDFs that were all fill in forms saved using Save As.  Searching the issue it's because each PDF has the same form fields so only the first document has values and the rest are blank.  Since we keep all the source files I just want to flatten the PDFs and combine them, I don't need to go through and dynamically rename the fields.  I have tried multiple different things like trying to get the form and flatten it and then use that for the merge:

```
Dim form As PdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(newDoc, True)
form.FlattenFields()
merger.Merge(form.GetPdfDocument, 1, newDoc.GetNumberOfPages())
```

But I keep throwing a error trying to use the form document like this.  So I rewrote it using temp files for the flattened document like this:

```
Dim merger As New PdfMerger(New PdfDocument(New PdfWriter(outputPath)))
For Each pdfFile In pdfFiles
    Dim myTempFile As String = Path.GetTempFileName
    Dim myDoc As New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(pdfFile), New PdfWriter(myTempFile))
    Dim myForm As PdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(myDoc, False)
    myForm.FlattenFields()
    myDoc.Close()
    Dim flattenedDoc As New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(myTempFile))
    merger.Merge(flattenedDoc, 1, flattenedDoc.GetNumberOfPages)
    flattenedDoc.Close()
    File.Delete(myTempFile)
Next
merger.Close()
```

This *works* but when you open the document in Adobe it says "An error exists on the page.  Adobe may not display the page correctly.  Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem." but I don't see anything wrong.

Is there a way to do this all in memory, load the PDFs, flatten them, merge them, and save it all to a file?  The work around is working but with the error message.  Or is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**

The entire function if needed: https://pastebin.com/K0ea6dSA

Test files:  [Test File 1](https://upload.disroot.org/r/8Fpq7mJC#VQTww3Kb/4XpMlRVm1R+3140nru7hIOSDkaBRDtYiAs=)   [Test File 2](https://upload.disroot.org/r/sNsRvSAv#wDIysqIkIxdlYsKo8IT+kRdbjqDICosnePp1gWFJRL4=)   [Output File](https://upload.disroot.org/r/Qeo6Jnuw#wvBoLF4XJnci+gLjaX2hIBaV0jsZdgeodmdcW+iVOdU=)

Comment: Can you share an example document illustrating the issue? Both in its state before and after?

Comment: https://file.io/US0zRna1a0z1  Two pdfs.  Each is fine by itself but once merged using the code above Adobe throws the error.  This seems to happen on any form PDF that flatten where I'm combining a bunch of "Save As" copies.

Comment: https://file.io/US0zRna1a0z1 -  *The transfer you requested has been deleted*

Comment: @KJ thanks!   @ ADY Please also share the result of merging those files with your rewritten code that merges with flattening and temp files.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to understand the examples on dynamically renaming fields so they would all be unique but I couldn't get those to work either. So I was just going to flatten them since it doesn't matter. That and we could be merging 10 "identical" forms together so that's a lot of fields to rename for no real reason.  I've added persistent links to the two input files and the output file to the post along with the entire function.

Comment: What is also odd is in the source files the third set of check boxes the top is checked and in the output there is no check mark and the field looks disabled.  I'm going to edit the source file and see if I can find anything.  I still think there should be a better way to do what I'm ding without temp files in between but maybe not.

Comment: Looked in the source and there isn't anything different that I see between all the check boxes, they are copy and paste (check box1, check box2, etc).  So the fact it's acting differently with that one doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the original PDFs, a broken entry of the normal **Yes** appearance of *Check Box5*. During flattening iText adds a reference to the that appearance as form XObject to the static page content.

Now we know that Adobe Acrobat (Reader) warns about some errors in PDFs while it silently repairs other errors without further ado. Here we see that behavior in action, the same error in an XObject is warned about if that XObject is referenced from the static page content, while it is silently repaired/ignored if the XObject is only the normal **Yes** appearance of a widget annotation.

Thus, iText doesn't create the erroneous object, it merely re-uses it in a context where Adobe Acrobat is more sensitive...

---

The error in detail:

The normal **Yes** appearance of *Check Box5* (the top checkbox in the "Overrides" row) looks like this:

```
38 0 obj
<</BBox[0.0 0.0 9.38184 9.16364]/Filter/FlateDecode/FormType 1/Length 122/Matrix[114 0 R 113 0 R 110 0 R 115 0 R 117 0 R 118 0 R 119 0 R 120 0 R 121 0 R 122 0 R 123 0 R 124 0 R 125 0 R 126 0 R 127 0 R 128 0 R 129 0 R 130 0 R 131 0 R 132 0 R 133 0 R 134 0 R 135 0 R 136 0 R 137 0 R 138 0 R 139 0 R]/Resources<</Font<</ZaDb 116 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text]>>/Subtype/Form/Type/XObject>>stream
...
endstream
endobj
```

Here the **Matrix** entry should have been an array containing 6 numbers (like `[1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0]` as in many other appearances) but it actually is an array with references to the 27 form widget annotations.

---

Concerning your main questions:

> Is there a way to do this all in memory, load the PDFs, flatten them, merge them, and save it all to a file? The work around is working but with the error message. Or is there a better way to do this?

The work-around is necessary but you can use memory streams instead of temporary files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'll attempt to edit the original file and fix the error.  As for the work around I suppose if it's working and I clean up my temp files I'll just leave it as is.

Comment: Thanks again @mkl.  Fixed the error in the PDF and now I have no issues merging copies of the same form.  I've also decided just to keep the temp files in place instead of memory streams, it looks cleaner in the code and for me it's easier to troubleshoot when something is wrong.